# What is going on behind the Pandas scenes that is causing a level in a MultiIndex not to be dropped?

Tags: python, pandas, multi-index

Consider the data frame `df`
Note that the columns object is a single level MultiIndex.

```
midx = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([list('AB')])
df = pd.DataFrame(1, range(3), midx)

   A  B
0  1  1
1  1  1
2  1  1
```

Now when I reference column `'A'`

```
df.A

   A
0  1
1  1
2  1
```

I get a single column data frame and not the series object I expected.  Consequently, I can indefinitely reference this column.

```
df.A.A.A.A.A

   A
0  1
1  1
2  1
```

As another check, I used `xs`

```
df.xs('A', axis=1)

   A
0  1
1  1
2  1
```

Same problem.
`pd.IndexSlice`?

```
df.loc[:, pd.IndexSlice['A']]

   A
0  1
1  1
2  1
```

How about `squeeze`

```
df.A.squeeze()

0    1
1    1
2    1
Name: (A,), dtype: int64
```

This isn't at all what I expected.

1. What is preventing this from turning into a series object with the name of `'A'`?
2. What is the most intuitive way to fix this?
3. Is there any good reason why we should ever want a single level `MultiIndex`?

Comment: don't know answers  but I am glad to see this intelligent question!

Comment: Wow... it is tough converting that pd.MultiIndex with one level to a regular index.

Comment: It is hard to answer all of the question here... but I find a way to fix it ..`df.A.iloc[:,0]`

Comment: @Wen that leaves the name of the Series as `('A',)` and not `'A'`

Comment: @piRSquared yep , you are right just notice that

Comment: This is probably a bug, as I suspect single level `MultiIndex` aren't very well tested.  It was previously difficult to construct one, as `MultiIndex.from_product` would return a regular `Index` in the case of your example. It wasn't until 0.21.0 that this behavior was supported (see [#17236](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/pull/17236)), which was basically the last pandas release, since 0.22.0 only really contained a single change.

Answer (score 1):

I wrote this to fix the problem.

```
def fix_single_level_multiindex(midx):
    return midx.get_level_values(0) if midx.nlevels == 1 else midx
```

Or

```
def fix_single_level_multiindex(midx):
    return midx.levels[0][midx.labels[0]] if midx.nlevels == 1 else midx
```